# What is bound method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, jsx

[This React.js doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs) mentions about so-called *bound method on the class* without actually explaining the concept and showing a single line of code. How would it look like the *bound method on the class* in React.js/JSX case from the codebase perspective?

Comment: That's not a React-/JSX-specific thing, just general JS. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. They do show you why and how to bind in the React docs, too: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh wow so it's simply binding via 'bind'. The different naming confused me.

Comment: It's the same word, just a different tense. If I bind a method, I get a bound method. That means I have bound a method in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bind method gives you the possibility of keeping a reference to the class in which your function is declared. Refer: [MDN binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

In React you need to bind a function only when you need to call it on a different class, a very simple example will be:

```
export default class Parent extends React.component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    // some stuff here
  }

  render() {
    return(<Button onClick={this.handleClick})
  }
}
```

So when the onClick method of the Button component is called, it will call the handleClick method of your Parent class.

Comment: oh so sorry. im take care of it on  my next post. thanks

Comment: that's ok, but note that you can [edit] this one too